# Strange notation $\delta$ and colon

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, matrix-calculus

I am readintg a tutorial regarding fluid mechanics and I encountered this strange $\delta$ notation:$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}\partial\mathbf{F}}:\delta\mathbf{F}&=\delta\left(\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}}\right)\\
&=......(\text{other calculations})
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, $\mathbf{F}$ is $3\times3$ matrix, $\Psi$ is a scalar function of $\mathbf{F}$.

I just get totally confused by the notation $\delta$ and the colon (:) used here. I guess that here the $\delta$ notation refers to "differential", just like the $d$ notation in, for example, $\int f(x)dx$. But through this tutorial, there are other places using the $d$ notation, and why do the author use a different manner here?

Also, what exactly does the ":" notation mean here? I suppose this means that the derivative is taken with respect to $\mathbf{F}$? I can't find enough evidance to prove this.

Besides, the author suggests in the following context that, we have:$$
\delta[\det(\mathbf{F})]=(\det\mathbf{F})\mathbf{F}^{-T}:\delta\mathbf{F} \tag{1}
$$
As far as I know, if you take a derivative over a determinant of a matrix, say $X$, you get (using notations that are more familiar to me):$$
d(\det(X))=\text{tr}(\det(X)X^{-1}dX)
$$
It does not seem to like the form of equation (1) above. What is confusing to me is where the transpose of equation (1) come from, and, does equation (1) even mean taking the differentiate...?

Can somebody help me with that? Don't need to solve all the questions, just kindly drop a comment or a few hints and I would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Please include the name of the book or a link to tutorial, notation is not always standard between authors. $\delta$ usually refers to the functional derivative. But it’s not clear here if that is necessarily the case. The colon might be referring to a composition. Making your top thing look like a chain rule (depending on what “other calculations” entails).

Comment: Could the colon mean "such that" as we sometimes see in set notation: $\{x : x^2 = 3\}$

Comment: The colon denotes a [double dot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic) (or double contraction) product.  It is commonly used in Continuum Mechanics.  When the operands are matrices it corresponds to the matrix inner product which can be expressed in terms of the trace function $$A:B = {\rm Tr}\left(A^TB\right) = \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}\,B_{ij}$$

Comment: Also the differential of the determinant should really be written as
$$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
d\LR{\det F} = \LR{\det F} \LR{F^{-1}}^T:dF
$$

Comment: Thank you very much @greg, I understand now. And I missed one $\mathbf{F}$ in the original post and I'll edit it.

Comment: @greg could you please also explain what does the first equation, i.e.$$\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}\partial\mathbf{F}}:\delta\mathbf{F}=\delta\left(\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}}\right)$$ mean? Why do one take the double dot of $\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}\partial\mathbf{F}}$ and $\delta\mathbf{F}$ and gets $\delta\left(\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\mathbf{F}}\right)$? More generally, do we have:$$\frac{df(X)}{dX}:dX=d(f(X))$$ for arbitrary function $f$ and matrix $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\A{{\cal A}}
\def\B{{\cal B}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$When applied to tensors, the double-contraction product sums over the last two indices of the first tensor and the first two indices of the second tensor.

For example, writing  $\,\C = \A:\B\,$ in index notation yields
$$\large{
\C_{ab\ldots il\ldots yz}
 = \sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{k=1}^K
   \,\A_{ab\ldots i\c{jk}}\,\B_{\c{jk}l\ldots yz}
}$$
In your example, $\Psi$ is a scalar, $F$ is a matrix, the gradient is also a matrix, and the Hessian is a fourth-order tensor. Once again, index notation makes this clear
$$\eqalign{
G_{ij} &= \grad{\Psi}{F_{ij}} \qiq
\H_{ijkl} = \grad{G_{ij}}{F_{kl}}
 = \grad{^2\Psi}{F_{kl}\:\p F_{ij}}
 = \grad{^2\Psi}{F_{ij}\:\p F_{kl}}
\\
}$$
The differential of the gradient can then be written as
$$\eqalign{
dG
 &= \H:dF \qiq dG_{ij}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3\H_{ijkl}\:dF_{kl} \\
}$$
and the differential of the scalar function as
$$\eqalign{
d\Psi &= G:dF\;=\; \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 G_{ij}\:dF_{ij} \\
}$$
You can also write the second order Taylor expansion as
$$\eqalign{
\def\D{\Delta}
\def\DF{\D F}
\D\Psi
 &\,=\, G:\DF \;\;{\bf+}\;\; \tfrac12\DF:\H:\DF \\
}$$